# Using code-first migrations with different schemas

Tags: azure, entity-framework-migrations, azure-mobile-services

I have a test mobile service `myservice_test` and a production mobile service `myservice` and I turned on code-first migrations.

When I create the initial migration or a new migration, the code that is generated includes a schema name:

```
CreateTable("myservice.Groups",...
```

I want to be able to run the migrations on both services.

The problem is that my test server uses a different schema than my production server - as far as I can tell, the instance uses the service name as the schema name.

Because the generated code contains the schema name, it can only be run on one server but not the other.

What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing: I made sure all instances use the same schema. To do that, I had to manage the dbs myself.

Let's say I have 2 instances - `myservice` and `myservice_test`. Each have its own sql server instance with db's `myservice_db` and `myservice_test_db` respectively.

In each db, I create the same schema - `myservice` and a login and user with permissions to this schema.

In `web.config` I added (or edited) the schema name in `appSettings` section:

```
<add key="MS_TableSchema" value="myservice" />
```

Now everyone is working with the same schema name.

But... it is not possible to change the `MS_TableConnectionString` for mobile services instances to use the new schema. I ended up creating a new `ConnectionString` app setting and used that instead. In each instance I overrode this setting to connect to the correct server and db.

Comment: That's the best way to do it, by having a custom connection string that you use in both instances.